# Notation for power of prime in prime factorization

Tags: notation, prime-factorization

What's the accepted shorthand for the power of a prime in the prime factorization of a natural number?

For example, $35 000 = 2^3 5^4 7$, so what would the notation be for $f_5(35 000) = 4, f_2(35 000) = 3$, $f_7(35 000) = 1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notation/name for the number of times a number can be exactly divided by $2$ (or a prime $p$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54965/notation-name-for-the-number-of-times-a-number-can-be-exactly-divided-by-2-or)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$ is sometimes called the [$p$-adic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) or $p$-adic additive valuation and denoted $\nu_p(n)$, but I don't think this notation is universal.

Comment: Is that a "nu"?

Comment: Yes. You can determine this by clicking the "edit" button, if you have access to that, or by viewing the source.